# Timer should appear in the online test page as we scroll down

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I am working on my online test project and i am facing problem with these Aspects.

- I have placed **a timer on top of the Page** and the problem is
- As **i scroll down the page loaded**  with questions **the timer should also come along with the page as i scroll down**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the timer with an `HTML div` and use css `position:fixed` property.[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed) is an example how they do it.